# Express $C$ interms of the sets $A_n$

Tags: continuity

[NBHM_2006_PhD Screening Test_Analysis]

> Let $f$ be a real valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ define
>   $$w_j(x)=\sup\{|f(u)-f(v)|: u,v\in [x-1/j,x+1/j]\}$$ $j\in \mathbb{N}$
>   and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, Define next
>   $$A_{j,n}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:w_j(x)<1/n\}$$ $n=1,2,\dots$ and
>   $$A_n=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j,n}$$ Now let $$C=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: f
> > \text{ is continuos at }x\}$$ How to express $C$ interms of $A_n$?

Well, according to the definition, $f$ iss continuos at $x$ iff $w_j(x)=0$ (I guess, I can do that by definition of continuity).

Then I guess, $C=\bigcap A_n$. I am not sure.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$
Hi, you are right about $C$. We have for $x \in \mathbb R$:
\begin{align*}
   f \text{ is continuous at } x &\iff \forall n \exists j \forall y: \abs{x-y} \le \frac 1j \Rightarrow \abs{f(x) - f(y)} < \frac 1n\\
   &\iff \forall n \exists j :\sup_{\abs{x-y} \le \frac 1j} \abs{f(x)-f(y)} < \frac 1n\\
   &\iff \forall n \exists j: w_j(x) < \frac 1n\\
   &\iff \forall n \exists j :x \in A_{j,n}\\
   &\iff x \in \bigcap_n \bigcup_j A_{j,n}
 \end{align*}

Comment: thank you martini for making thessse precise :)